# Taking out a part of a maven project as a module

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a maven module `A` that is dependent on the classes in the module `B` (both are child modules in a project).

In the `A`'s `pom.xml` I have the following:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>test.pack</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency> 
  </dependencies>
```

But when I try to build the `A`, the `B` does not appear in the dependencies correctly, I get compilation errors in the class that is in the `A`'s `test.pack.packFromA` package in the import statement, which looks like `import test.pack.packFromB.*`.

So, my `B` dependency doesn't work correctly. But I thought classes from the `B` would be packed and added in the classpath, so I could use them. I tried to add `<type>` in that dependency, but that didn't help. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
The `<modules>` part of parent's `pom.xml` looks like that:

```
  <modules>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>A</module>
  </modules>
```

Here is the error I get: `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project A: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:`

Comment: Could you add the parent pom's <modules> section? If you refer in module A to module B the it  should be compiled before module A

Comment: @Lexandro Thanks for reply, I'll add it now. I also tried to move B's war in my Maven local repository, but it didn't work. Does it need to be done?

Comment: @Lexandro I also added the error, and, well, sorry, if A and B names are making this description not really a good one.

Comment: Have you added the parent in project A and B to your parent?

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry, I'm a little confused about your question. I have <parent> sections in both A and B, if that's what you are asking about.

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes that's what i meant. Ok. Your compiling error looks like you missed some dependency. Not correctly defined dependency...Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10371731/296328 how it looks like. BTW: Did you call mvn clean package from the root folder of your project?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, that's what my question is about. So, do you mean that if the dependencies are well written, I shouldn't have problems with importing classes from B in some classes of the A module?

Comment: @khmarbaise I did the mvn clean in the parent's folder, I also did mvn install in the B folder. But I get the error about packages from B (which in used by A) that are imported in A's class, that do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done `mvn install` in module B, before you tried to build module A?

(If you do "mvn package" instead of `mvn install`, module B won't be placed in the repo, so Maven won't find it when building module A).

Also, have you tried building the multi-module project from the parent module? (When you do this, Maven will build the modules in the correct order)

If that's not it, verify that the classes you are referencing are located under `src/main/java/test/pack/packFromB` in module B. If they are under `src/test/java..` you need a specific type of dependency for that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I did all that and the folders structure should be a correct one. But, probably, the installation was not as successful as I thought, so I'll try to redo all that.

Comment: I'll mark this one as the best answer, because it's really good as soon as I didn't give a full description of my problem. In fact, I was trying to add a war dependency, which appeared to be a bad idea. But then I made separate jar dependencies, installed and cleaned. Now it works like a charm (and I'm really glad to say that :) ), thanks a lot, it's still a helpful answer.

Comment: Sweet! Yeah, depending on a war will explode that war and include it into your war, if I remember correctly..