# Maven multi module project run on tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, web, tomcat7, multi-module

I've a maven multi module project with structure defined as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371731/3529309

I want to run this project on tomcat using maven, by not making war and then deploy on server but using maven plugin for this.

I've added this plugin in web module.

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>mytomcat</server>
                    <path>/BATest</path>
                    <username>tomcat</username>
                    <password>s3cret</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And running root project using `package tomcat7:run`

But getting error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] desktop
[INFO] JavaLearning
[INFO] web
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 6.2 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 9.3 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] desktop ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] JavaLearning ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] web ................................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.897 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-07T18:25:07+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/108M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (D:\Development\MAVEN_REPO), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

This method is working fine in simple maven web project. Please help for multi module maven project.

Comment: Please read the error message: `No plugin found for prefix 'tomcat7' in ...`. You have to give `mvn package org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:run`....